# can you hurt relations with Sylgja if you want to marry her and complete Farkas's Quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Farkas gives you a quests to start a fist fight with certain NPCs, Sylgja in Shor's Stone is one of them but you can also marry her

i'm wondering if there is any adverse effects from completing Farkas's quest before you marry her or if after you marry her if she can still be targted

Comment: Everybody seems to be happy after you beat them with your fists. I think I should try making friends this way in the _real world_.

Comment: @ninten i live in Australia, if it worked in the real world then all the drunken fighting at pubs would make Australia the happiest place in the world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no negative impications. People who you win against in fist fights usually rather admire you for winning against them.

In principle, negative outcomes of one quest for a NPC will not affect future quests. For example, if you side with the Stormcloaks and win the war, all the Jarls defeated will gather in Solitude. While they will normally snarl at you if you visit them there, you can still finish quests given by them, and they will become happy and friendly if the outcome of the quest is in their favor.